# Select data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I join multiple rows in just one single row through mysql?

Example :

Student Table

```
Sno.|  Name |  Subjects
1.  | ABC   |  1
2.  | ABC   |  3
3.  | ABC   |  4
4.  | FMC   |  2
5.  | ABC   |  4
6.  | JBC   |  4
```

Papers Table:

```
Sno. | Paper Name | Type 
 1.      French     Optional
 2.      English    Mandatory
 3.      Japenese   Optional
 4.      Maths      Optional
```

Now I want it in this format

```
Sno.| Name|   Sub1  |  Sub2    | Sub3  |  Sub4 |
1.  | ABC |  French |  Japenese| Maths | Null  |
2.  | FMC |  Null   | Null     | Null  | Null  |
3.  | JBC |  Maths  | Null     | Null  | Null  |
```

What i want to select is papers name from papers table and student name, four subjects from the other table. I only want to see those paper which are optional. I am not sure what to do?

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at mysql `JOIN` statement and come back if you fail understanding the usage with a more specific question.

Comment: I have tried Join query and few other queries as well. It didn't work. The problem is i have converted my vertical table into a horizontal one but i am not sure how to fetch paper name from the paper table where the type is optional.

Comment: @favoretti The query i run to change it from vertical to horizontal is : SELECT  t1.Name, 
        MIN(t1.Subject) AS Sub1,
        MIN(t2.Subject) AS Sub2,
        MIN(t3.Subject) AS Sub3,
        MIN(t4.Subject) AS Sub4
FROM    Students t1
        LEFT JOIN Students T2 
            ON t1.Name = t2.Name 
            AND t2.Subject > t1.Subject
        LEFT JOIN Students T3 
            ON t2.Name = t3.Name 
            AND t3.Subject > t2.Subject
        LEFT JOIN Students T4 
            ON t3.Name = t4.Name 
            AND t4.Subject > t3.Subject
GROUP BY t1.Name;

Comment: @IPerfect and you suggest to change query every time when subject table was edited?

Comment: @Hast, sorry couldn't understand you.

Comment: @IPerfect, Hast is saying that you will have to add a few more line if, eg., you add Science (of optional Type) in the Paper Table.  Things get much easier if you can output the results vertically.

Comment: Here's some ideas based on your query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03479/7/0

Comment: I think _Maths_ should be _Sub4_ for Student _ABC_ in your Example.

Comment: I think a better name for the question is: _"pivoting with multiple tables in msql"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept you are looking for is **pivoting**.

#### Version with *join*

```
select 
  name,
  max(if(s.subject = 1 and p.type = 'Optional', p.paper_name, null)) as subject1,
  max(if(s.subject = 2 and p.type = 'Optional', p.paper_name, null)) as subject2,
  max(if(s.subject = 3 and p.type = 'Optional', p.paper_name, null)) as subject3,
  max(if(s.subject = 4 and p.type = 'Optional', p.paper_name, null)) as subject4
from 
  students s
inner join
  papers p on p.sno = s.subject
group by s.name
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5c03/23/0)

#### Version with *subselects* instead of a join

```
select 
  name,
  max(
    case 
      when subject = 1 
        then (select paper_name from papers p where p.sno = subject and type = 'Optional') 
      else 
        null 
    end) as subject1, 
  max(
    case 
      when subject = 2 
        then (select paper_name from papers p where p.sno = subject and type = 'Optional') 
      else 
        null 
    end) as subject2,
  max(
    case 
      when subject = 3 
        then (select paper_name from papers p where p.sno = subject and type = 'Optional') 
      else 
        null 
    end) as subject3,
  max(
    case 
      when subject = 4
        then (select paper_name from papers p where p.sno = subject and type = 'Optional') 
      else 
        null 
    end) as subject4
from 
  students
group by 
  name
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5c03/15/0)

Comment: Another question about pivoting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table